# How to remove duplicate element using regex?

Tags: html, regex, node.js

I am using Node.js.

I have problem to handle the following string

```
 <em><em>                - first Occurrence 
 <em><em><em>            - second Occurrence 
 <em><em><em><em>        - third Occurrence 
 <em><em><em><em><em>    - fourth Occurrence
```

How to remove multiples and make it single  tag only?

Any one assist me to handle.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am trying the regex   "`(<em>(<em>)?)`"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find:

```
(<em>)+
```

And replace with `<em>`.

This will find one ore more (`+`) occurrences of `<em>`, one after another. Then all of those will be replaced with a single `<em>`, thereby removing duplicate tags

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/oF6tZ2/1)</kbd>

---

Here is the reason your RegEx does not work:

```
(
<em>         # Captures first <em>
(<em>)?      # Optional <em>
)
```

So this will capture, at most, `<em><em>`. This works on the first occurrence, but not on the other.If there are `<em><em><em>`, the first 2 get merged into one, however the last one is still left.

So for your RegEx to work, you would have to run it multiple times (i.e. replace on the original string, then replace on the new replaced string, then replace on that, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming there can be any tag and not only `em` you are concerned about. So I am using `.+` in my regex

```
console.log("<em><em><em><em>".replace(/(<.+?>)+/, "$1"))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/OYnboh)**